# Is it possible to execute javascript code using any method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am initializing JavaScript code to string variable at run time. How to execute stored JavaScript code.

Comment: Need to clarify better what you're doing. In general, it's inadvisable to execute javascript code from a string (which would involve using eval())

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Please show us what you get. give us an example.

Comment: When wouldyou like to run this? On some event? Your code can help :)

Comment: @P.Prabhakaran B.E Eval !!! horrible idea. eval is Evil.  The eval function is the most misused feature of JavaScript. Avoid it.http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `eval`

```
var code = "alert('sdfdf');";
eval(code); // this will execute the code inside the string
```

### NOTE: Using eval is a bad idea.

Comment: Don't forget advising against its use.

Comment: Yaaaa that is more important...